# How to get the current window in focus with the Task Switcher (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, windows, accessibility

I started hacking away on a tiny screen reader project the other day (it'll probably never take off, but everyone needs a hobby, plus it's a tool that I use on the daily, why not make my own)?
Anyways, I currently only have support for getting the active foreground window text with win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()). Every time that window changes, SAPI 5 speaks it. However, I am now facing a problem.
The Task Switcher. Aaaargh, the Task Switcher. When holding down the Alt key and pressing the Tab key (which is how we screen reader users change our active window), I only get spoken, "Task Switching." And have to release both the alt and tab keys to know what the current window focused in the Task Switcher is. This is, obviously, not ideal, as A, it's something all screen readers do, and B, I have no idea when I get to the window I want.
So here's my question:
How do I determine what window has focus on the task switcher? E.G., if I had Brave open in one window, and command prompt in the next, when I pressed alt tab, without releasing alt, I should hear it speak that command prompt is focused.
*Sighs... This probably has to do with keyboard hooks or something, which I'll need at some point, but I didn't think this soon... :(.
Thanks in advance, and sorry if the question was a bit of a rant...

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure, perhaps this might be of interest https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227203/kwin-modifying-the-task-switcher-to-raise-all-windows

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This appears to be for Linux however, and this is a Windows project. Sorry for not stating that in the initial post.